# ASP.NET Master Pages - Style selected nav link

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, master-pages

I'm building a public facing Sharepoint site and have gotten it all built, but I'm wondering; is there any way to give a specific nav link different styling if it is the selected link? The entire layout is custom HTML/CSS, so there's not any Sharepoint stuff in the way. Since it is separated from the site content pages, I don't see any obvious way of doing this.

For an example of what I'm trying to do, see the impressed store button on the Apple site: http://store.apple.com/us

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, here is my solution: Give each menu item an ID, and javascript on each page to change the styling of the associated menu item. I'm not too familiar with Web Forms, but this is the only way I could come up with to do this.